# How to add EnvironmentFile directive to systemctl using Docker with centos7/httpd base image

Tags: apache, docker, centos, dockerfile, systemd

I am not sure if this is possible without creating my own base image, but I use environment variables in `/etc/environment` on our servers and typically make them accessible to apache by doing the following:

```
$ printf "HTTP_VAR1=var1-value\n\
HTTP_VAR2=var2-value"\
 >> /etc/environment
$ mkdir /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
$ printf "[Service]\n\
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment"\
 > /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/environment.conf
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl restart httpd
$ reboot
```

The variables are then available in any PHP calls to `getenv('HTTP_VAR1');` and etc. However, in running this from a docker file I get dbus errors on the systemctl commands. Without the systemctl commands it seems the variables are not available to apache as it seems the new EnvironmentFile directive doesn't take effect. My docker file snippet:

```
FROM centos/httpd:latest

RUN printf "HTTP_VAR1=var1-value\n\
HTTP_VAR2=var2-value"\
 >> /etc/environment

RUN mkdir /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d &&\
 printf "[Service]\n\
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment"\
 > /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/environment.conf

RUN systemctl daemon-reload &&\
 systemctl restart httpd

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Try removing  "RUN systemctl daemon-reload &&\
 systemctl restart httpd" ..

Comment: That's the thing, if I remove those, my EnvironmentFile does not seem to get loaded by apache. On a live server I have to run those two commands to make the EnvironmentFile take effect.

Comment: Okay..typically the docker images have the software configured differently..you may have to look into httpd image to understand how to inject the variablea

Comment: So am I to believe that you think that the EnvironmentFile addition should get picked up without the daemon-reload? Because that won't happen for sure on a real server, you have to daemon-reload and reload apache after that. Not sure why docker server would be any different.

Comment: The only difference in docker environment is that the processes run in foreground, so some of the configs may work differently. But it should not be hugely different. Looking at the dockerfile of the base image should give you good clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I happened upon the answer to the issue today. It seems that systemd drops backslashes inside single quotes, but it may effect double-quotes too from what I saw in testing. I found the [systemd development mailing list thread from April 2014 where patching the issue was being discussed](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-April/018577.html). It seems as though the fix never made it in. So we have to work around it.

In attempting to work around it I noticed some issues with actually reading the variables at all. It seemed as though either Apache or php-cli would get the correct variables, and sometimes not at all, it took a bit of sleuthing to figure out what was going on. Then I started reading into the [systemd's EnvironmentFile directive](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) to see if there was more to gain from the docs. It turns out it does not evaluate bash so export won't work. It expects a text file with variable assignments and herein lies one of the main issues that might keep this from being resolved.

I then devised a workable solution. Utilizing [systemd's ExecStartPre directive](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) I am able to run a script on startup of the httpd service. I then read in the environment file and write a new plain text one that will then be used by httpd's systemd unit. Here is the code:

Firstly, I moved my variables to `/etc/profile.d/` directory rather than `/etc/environment` file.

**file:** `/etc/profile.d/environment.sh`
This is where we store all our environment variables, this gets easily sourced on all interactive shell logins. In the rarer cases where we need to have these variables available non-interactively we can either provide `--login` flag to `/bin/bash` or source it manually.

```
export HTTP_VAR1=var1-value-with-a-back\slash
export HTTP_VAR2=var2-value
```

**file:** `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/environment.conf`
Our drop-in unit file to extend how the httpd service works. I add in a script that runs before httpd starts up. This gets ran on all httpd restarts and starts. The script that runs generates a plain text file at `/etc/profile.d/environment.env` which we subsequently tell systemd to load as an EnvironmentFile.

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/generate-plain-environment-file"
EnvironmentFile=/etc/profile.d/environment.env
```

**file:** `/usr/local/bin/generate-plain-environment-file`
Here is the script I am using, I whipped this together really fast, I really don't think it is that robust and it could be better. It just removes the `export` from the beginning of the lines and then escapes any backslashes since systemd drops single backslashes. A more proper solution might be to use bash to evaluate each line and obtain the variable value in case of usage of variables or other bash in the actual bash variables, then output them as plain text name=value assignments, however this is not part of my use-case so I didn't bother.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /etc/profile.d/
rm -rf "./environment.env"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  echo $(echo "${line}" | sed 's/^export //' | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g') >> "./environment.env";
done < "./environment.sh"
```

**file:** `/etc/profile.d/environment.env`
This is the resulting file generated by the described script.

```
HTTP_VAR1=var1-value-with-a-back\\slash
HTTP_VAR2=var2-value
```

Conclusion is that the I now have two files with the same thing in them but I only need to maintain the one, the other is generated each time we restart httpd. Also, we fix the backslash issue in the process. Hurray!